# How would this be proved using continuity?

Tags: real-analysis

k is a real continuous function such that $k(a)< 0$ for some a and k(x) tends to 0 as x tends to positive and negative infinity.  Prove that k is bounded below and attains its lower bound.

Comment: Write out the statement for what it means for $k(x)$ to tend to $0$ as $x$ tends to positive and negative infinity. This should give you two values $a < 0, b > 0$ such that below $a$ and above $b$, $k$ is bounded. Then, consider what happens to continuous functions on $[a, b].$

Comment: Hint: $k(a)<0$ for some $a$ is only required to show that $k$ attains its lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

Since both limits tend to $0$, we know that there are $m,n\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x\in(-\infty,m)\cup (n,\infty)$ we have $|k(x)|<\epsilon$ for some specified $\epsilon>0$.

We can choose $\epsilon<|k(a)|$. Then, becaues $k$ is continuous, it is bounded on the compact interval $[m,n]$. It attains a minimum on this interval by the Extreme Value Theorem, and this min will be the absolute minimum of the function because $$\min_{x\in [m,n]}k(x)<k(a)<\min\{k(x):x\in(-\infty,m)\cup (n,\infty)\}$$

So it is bounded and attains its lower bound.